# Difference between Gaussian blur tools in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur

I want to apply a Gaussian blur to an image I imported into Illustrator. There are 2 tools from the menu, Effect-Blur-Gaussian Blur and Effect-SVG Filters-AI_GaussianBlur_4. I have applied both effects (using 4 as the radius for the normal blur). They appear almost the same, but not quite e.g. the SVG blur appears to be more intense and also blurs the edges of the image. What are the differences between these and which one is best for which purpose please?

Comment: The svg blur is meant to be used only as part of svg export. 2 different technology stacks. The svg filter is an example you can modify it. They are not supposed to be different per see just that the way svg works means they are. The svg filter layer is a bit flaky in terms of implementation. Also it measures units differently. Situation is the same in PS with gaussian and filter custom

Comment: What if I post it as an answer? Lol